# PHP: OOP constructors signatures

Tags: oop, constructor, php-7

I've class called Books

```
  class Books {
      /* Member variables */
      var $price;
      var $title;

        function __construct( $title, $price ) {
           $this->title = $title;
           $this->price = $price;
        }

      /* Member functions */
      function getPrice(){
         echo $this->price ."<br/>";
      }


      function getTitle(){
         echo $this->title ." <br/>";
      }
   }
```

then I've added another class which inherit my Book class something like this

```
class Novel extends Books {
   var $publisher;


   function getPublisher(){
      echo $this->publisher. "<br />";
   }
  function __construct( $publisher ) {
    $this->publisher = $publisher;
  }
}
```

Now I want to invoke Novel class and set all of its properties such as title, price and publisher via constructor so if I do this

```
$physics = new Books("Physics for High School",1);
$testNovel = new Novel("Test Publisher");
```

it works great it set the publisher value of my $testNovel object 
so how can I set value of Title and price while creating object of it??

even If I try

```
$testNovel = new Novel("Test Title",4,"Test Pubisher");
```

here "Test Title" is set as publisher instead of "Test Publisher". Moreover, if I put more values inside signature something like this

```
$testNovel = new Novel("Test Title",4,"New Pub","","Whatever","","Why it allow");
```

it does not throw any error why??

Comment: Do you have `error_reporting` enabled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you extend a class that defines a constructor, with a class that defines it's own constructor, you need to call the parent constructor yourself supplying the required parameters. E.g.:

```
class Novel extends Books
{
    // ...

    function __construct($title, $price, $publisher)
    {
        $this->publisher = $publisher;

        parent::__construct($title, $price);
    }
}
```

---

From the [manual](https://php.net/manual/language.oop5.decon.php):

> **Note**: Parent constructors are not called implicitly if the child class
>   defines a constructor. In order to run a parent constructor, a call to
>   **parent::__construct()** within the child constructor is required. If the
>   child does not define a constructor then it may be inherited from the
>   parent class just like a normal class method (if it was not declared
>   as private).

Comment: $testNovel = new Novel("Test Title",4,"New Pub","","Whatever","","Why it allow"); 
it does not throw any error why??

Comment: @Jahangeer Because in php you can pass as many parameters as you like. The receiving function might throw an error on invalid parameters, but otherwise it's not an error.